# List cannot be resolved to a type and ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I'm learning the java collection framework and unable to figure out what is actually causing the error and here I'm using eclipse 4.18.0 and java version 15.
There is some problem in the setup because the code is working fine in vs code.

```
package lists;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class ArrayListCreate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        List<String> fruits=new ArrayList<>();
        fruits.add("Apple");
        System.out.println(fruits);
    }
}
```

Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
List cannot be resolved to a type
ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type

at lists.ArrayListCreate.main(ArrayListCreate.java:6)

Comment: `List<String> fruits=new ArrayList<>();` You need to specify the type of list to be created or use diamond operator

Comment: Still there is error

Comment: Something is weird here, as Matthew pointed out, compiler is complaining about error on `lists.ArrayListCreate.main(ArrayListCreate.java:21)` . But your file does not seem to be having even 10 lines. Are you sure you've shared complete file with us?

Comment: Please see the updated Question

Comment: I tried your updated code in my IntelliJ with jdk 1.11 and it seems to be building fine. I think there is some problem in your setup

Comment: I treid it on vs code and it is working fine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating generic classes you need to include the generic in the actual instantiation like `List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<String>();`.

That's actually a lie since you can make it simpler by just doing `List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();`. You can do this because it can infer the generic type from the left side of the line.

Comment: What version of java are you running and what exactly do you have now?

Comment: Also something I just noticed, the error is at line 21. Why is there 21 lines in the file

Comment: Its java 15.0.1

Comment: Other parts of the code are commented.Line 21: List<String> fruits=new ArrayList<>();